# How would I get the birthdays of friends who are celebrating their birthday this week, this month and next month using MYSQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working in an site which needs to get the birthdays of friends who are celebrating their birthday this week, this month and next month using MYSQL and PHP.

How would I go about this?

Comment: Well, the birthday part is not difficult if you have stored their birthdays in a db. The friend part might be tricky though, that is something you have to determine outside the db. Can take years sometimes to find out which of your friends are real friends etc... :)

Comment: You really should provide the relevant tables of the database you're working with, and whatever php you already have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided you store birthdates in DATE (or DATETIME) format in MySQL you can use the following Queries:

```
// This week
SELECT * FROM person WHERE WEEK( birthdate ) = WEEK( NOW() )

// This month
SELECT * FROM person WHERE MONTH( birthdate ) = MONTH( NOW() )

// Next month
```

<strike>SELECT * FROM person WHERE MONTH( birthdate ) = MONTH( NOW() ) + 1;</strike>

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE IF
  ( MONTH( NOW() ) < 12, MONTH( birthdate ) = MONTH( NOW() ) + 1,
  MONTH( birthdate ) = 1)
```

Comment: Your next month query will not work in December as `MONTH(NOW()) + 1 = 13`

Comment: Well spotted. The correct answer would be something like:

SELECT * FROM person WHERE IF ( MONTH( NOW() ) < 12, MONTH( birthdate ) = MONTH( NOW() ) + 1, MONTH( birthdate ) = 1)

Thanks for the remark.

Comment: For a person born on `Mar 1st`, this will return true during the whole `March`.

Comment: This condition: `MONTH('2009-03-01') = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)` holds for every date of `March`. `MONTH('2009-03-01')` returns `3` and same does `MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)`.

Comment: You can take the "simple" approach: SELECT YEAR( NOW() ) - YEAR( birthdate ) AS age FROM person

or you can be more precise: SELECT YEAR( NOW() ) - YEAR( birthdate ) - IF( DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , "%m%d" ) < DATE_FORMAT( birthdate, "%m%d" ), 1, 0 ) AS age FROM person

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users
WHERE   birthday + INTERVAL YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(birthday) YEAR BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

Note that this condition is not sargable and requires full indes scan.

In `SQL Server`, `Oracle` and `PostgreSQL` this can be improved using this approach:

- [**Selecting birthdays**](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/09/selecting-birthdays/)

, but `MySQL` lacks a way to generate a random resultset.

However, you can create a dummy table and store years from `1900` to `2100` in it.

Add a cron task to update it in `2100` since you can forget easily :)