# find the upcomming birthday in week

Tags: php, zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I get the birthdays of friends who are celebrating their birthday this week, this month and next month using MYSQL and PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486412/how-would-i-get-the-birthdays-of-friends-who-are-celebrating-their-birthday-this)

I have a mysql table of users with fields UserId, Username, Birthdate (format YYYY-MM-DD). I want to display something on my homepage like this:

Upcoming birthdays:
Fred Smith 24 Aug
Bill Jones 27 Aug
Sarah Connor 1 Sep
David Cassidy 5 Sep

You get the idea - it generates a short list of which birthdays are coming up next, ignoring the year, just based on the day and month. I just have no idea how to do the query - any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to create a function that will sit in a helper class, or go into your user class perhaps:-

```
/**
 * Fetches a list of birthdays coming up in the following week
 * @return array an array user's birthdays
 */
public function getBirthdays()
{
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTime(0, 0, 1);
    $today = $date->getTimestamp();
    $week = new DateInterval('P7D');
    $date->add($week);
    $date->setTime(23, 59, 59);
    $nextWeek = $date->getTimestamp();
    $select = new Zend_Db_Select(Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter());
    $select ->from('users', array('user_name', 'user_dob'))
            ->where('user_dob > ?', $today)
            ->where('user_dob < ?', $nextWeek);
    return $select->query()->fetchAll();
}
```

Then you just do:-

```
$birthdays = $classYouMade->getBirthdays();
$html = '';
foreach($birthdays as $bday){
     $html .= "Happy Birthday to {$bday['user_name']} on ";
     $html .= date('jS F', $bday['user_dob']) . '<br/>';
}
echo $html;
```

It's quite long, but is self documenting (I think) and you can come back to it in a year's time and see exactly what is happening at a glance.

I have ofcourse made some assumptions about how you are storing date etc (I always use unix timestamps), but I'm sure you can adapt it to your use case if you wish to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mysql `DATE_FORMAT()` function. This should give you all the birthdays between the current day, and 7 days from now:

`SELECT username, DATE_FORMAT(Birthdate,'%M %d') as 'birthday' FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Birthdate,'%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY), '%m-%d') ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(Birthdate,'%m-%d');`

Comment: I don't think this works if the current date is December 31.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to retrieve a list of your users as follow:

```
$adapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()
$table = $adapter->getDbTable() 
$select  = $table->select();
$select->where('active = ?', true); // if needed
$user = $table->fetchAll($select);
```

Your getDbTable would be something very similar to the one in [Zend Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) :

```
public function setDbTable($dbTable)
{
    if (is_string($dbTable)) {
        $dbTable = new $dbTable();
    }
    if (! $dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid table provided');
    }
    $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
    return $this;
}

public function getDbTable()
{
    if (null === $this->_dbTable) {
        $this->setDbTable('My_Users_DbTable_User');
    }
    return $this->_dbTable;
}
```

And in My/Users/DbTable/User a simpla class that contains:

```
class My_Users_DbTable_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'users';
}
```

Finally, when you retrieved your data from the database, you can iterate through each row you fetched using `current()` and `toArray()`methods. See [Zend_Db_Table_Row documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.table.row.html) for more details.

In order to display only the day and month of a birthdate, you can use [Zend_Date](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.date.html) which is pretty useful.

```
$date = "1970-12-10";
$d = new Zend_Date($date);
echo $d->toString(Zend_Date::DAY) . " " . $d->toString(Zend_Date::MONTH_NAME_SHORT);
// output: 10 Dec
```

Comment: That's a very roundabout way of getting a Zend_Db_Table. `$table = new Zend_Db_Table(array('name'=>'users', 'primary'=>'user_id'))` would do the job.

Comment: Your right vascowhite, I just took the Quickstart example because usually people are used to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can query this with something like:

```
SELECT username, birthdate FROM table WHERE birthdate >= beginning_of_week AND birthdate <= end_of_week
```

You'd probably have to calculate the week range you want in whatever script you're querying from.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the list with a simple SQL query:

```
select UserId, Username, Birthdate from Users where Birthdate >= CURDATE() and Birthdate <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL + 2 WEEK) order by Birthdate ASC
```

Then you can format the text using DateTime::format() in PHP.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $birthday = new DateTime($row['Birthdate']);
    print $row['Username']." ".$birthday->format('d M')."\n";
}
```