# Upcoming Birthdays in next 7 days SQL

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I get the birthdays of friends who are celebrating their birthday this week, this month and next month using MYSQL and PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486412/how-would-i-get-the-birthdays-of-friends-who-are-celebrating-their-birthday-this)

how can i query the database to get the birthdays in the next 7 days with this table layout

> ID - Int
>   Name - VarChar
>   DOB - Date

Answer (score 0):

that depends on the format you hold that `DOB`. If you hold it like `yyyy-mm-dd` than you could use a string compare, with a clause like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DOB <= 'computed_date'
```

where `computed_date` is built with string concatenation like:

```
$computed_date = sprintf('%4d-%2d-%2d', $year, $day, $month);
```